# Yii2 client validation does not work

Tags: validation, yii2

I have clean `yii2-advanced` template installed. I created a table in DB with `id` and `test` fields. In my `Model` I wrote `rule`:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['test'], 'required'],
    ];
}
```

Also I specified an unique `id` for my `form`.
But validation does not work. After typing smth to `control` and `focus out` I have an error in `console`: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'required' of undefined`. What can be a reason of this?

**EDIT:**

Model:

```
<?php
namespace backend\models;
use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
class ContactForm extends Model
{
    public $name;
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name'], 'required'],
        ];
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
?>
<div class="site-contact">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'contact-form']); ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput() ?>
                <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller action:

```
use backend\models\ContactForm;
public function actionContact()
{
    $model = new ContactForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        return $this->refresh();
    } else {
        return $this->render('contact', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use [Rules()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#rules()-detail), you must type the attribute (or array of attributes) first, and then the type of rule (that can be also a custom function by the way):

```
[['name'], 'required'] // setting the attribute "name" as required
```

you can read more about validation and rules [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html)

Comment: Sorry, I made a misprint. Column name is a `test`. Of course I did it way you wrote. And it throws described error.

Comment: If you still having problems with that, can you update the question with the model, the action of the controller and the form? I could not reproduce the error here. By the way, you are using MYSQL or MSSQL?

Answer (score 0):

if you have applied unique id for your form field, try removing it, Yii2 generates id by itself and applies validation message accordingly.